# Updating column in large Spanner table with concurrent writes

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I want to update a column in a large table (tens of millions of rows), without bringing our application down; i.e. there will be concurrent writes to the table. I want to do this in code (Java) since the update is non-trivial, and am wondering what the best way to do it is.

An efficient approach is to open a read transaction querying all rows, then loop over all these rows (`resultSet.next()`) while at the same time creating a series of read/write transactions with, say, 10,000 `INSERT_OR_UPDATE` mutations buffered in each transaction, containing the desired updates.

The problem is that this doesn't handle concurrent writes, since these steps can happen:

1. The read transaction mentioned above reads row X
2. Some separate transaction updates row X
3. The read/write transaction mentioned above uses data from step 1 and overwrites the update from step 2

To fix this, I can read the value back during the read/write transaction and verify that it hasn't changed, similar to [this example here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/transactions#rw_transaction_example), however this seems very slow (~50 ms per call, which translates to several weeks to update the whole table).

So how can I do this more efficiently? Thanks!

Comment: You write that you could read the value back during the read/write transaction and verify that it hasn't changed. What is it that you would do if it has changed? Use the changed value in the update? Or abort the entire update? Because the latter is no longer possible as the update is broken into several transactions. If you intend to just use the updated data, then you should follow a different strategy: Start a read/write transaction and read the first 10,000 rows you want to update, update these in the read/write tx and commit. Repeat with the following 10,000 rows until all rows are done.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just to clarify your suggestion: Do you mean to call `executeQuery` in the r/w transaction, loop over the resultset, and create and buffer all mutations? That indeed seems to work, and is efficient! And as for pagination, I guess I would have to use the where / order by / limit technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262605/how-do-i-implement-pagination#answer-42262606)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I'll add this as an answer as well, so that others that might have a similar question will find this thread easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do that would be not to use a read-only transaction, but to start a read/write transaction for each batch of 10,000 records, read the values you want to update in this read/write transaction and then update these 10,000 records in the same read/write transaction. Repeat this until all records have been updated.

So something like this:

1. Start read/write transaction
2. Read a batch of 10,000 records. Make sure that the order of the records is consistent by ordering on the primary key or some other unique (combination of) column(s). Limit the results by using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, so you get a query like this `SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE KEY>=@start AND KEY<@end LIMIT 10000`
3. Update the records and commit the transaction.
4. Repeat until all records have been updated.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out, and accept the answer if it works :) Btw, the OFFSET shouldn't be there right? Instead, one should use `WHERE key > lastValueRead`? Otherwise, rows could be missed if there are concurrent deletes.

Comment: You're right about the OFFSET. You should either limit the rows by `WHERE @key > @lastValueRead` or by ordering them by KEY and using LIMIT and OFFSET. I edited the example query to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you want to update the column - whether it is setting a constant value, or calculating a value based on other column(s) in the row.

You also don't say what the other updates to the table are, but I assume that they will involve modifications to this column, or modifications to other columns that affect this column..

Either way, [partitioned DML is a solution to this](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dml-partitioned)... 
Express your modification in the form of an update statement:

```
UPDATE table SET col1=123 WHERE col2=TRUE
```

Then run this as a partitioned DML (using API or [gcloud with the `--enable-partitioned-dml` flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/spanner/databases/execute-sql#--enable-partitioned-dml)) Spanner will split the operation up into multiple separate transactions, where each transaction would be internally consistent. Each DML transaction will only lock a sub-set of the rows in the table while running the transaction.

One issue with partitioned DML is that the expression will be run *at least once* on each row - due to retries - so the statement must be idempotent -- ie give the same results when executed multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The update is quite intricate and it'd be too much detail to describe it here, but I won't be able to represent it with a generic `UPDATE` statement, hence why I'm looking into iterating over all columns, and creating the update mutations in code (Java). If I could create multi-row updates like `UPDATE table SET (val=123 WHERE id=1 AND val=100) AND (val=234 WHERE id=2 AND val=200) AND ...` that might work (I'd then create this huge statement manually in code). But I don't think this can be done in Spanner.

Comment: yeah, for partitioned DML, you would have to perform the updates separately - you can only have one WHERE clause in an update. (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dml-syntax#update-statement), so for your case Knut's answer is better.